# can anyone find why is ths program to solve postfix expression giving runtime error

Tags: c

I was trying to solve a postfix expression but i don't understand why is it giving runtime error.
code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

struct stack
{  
    int top;
    int n[100];
}s;

void push(int a) 
{
    s.n[s.top+1]=a;
    s.top++;
}

void pop(char a)
{
    int c,b;
    b=s.n[s.top];    
    c=s.n[s.top-1];    

    s.top--;

    switch(a)
    {
       case '+':
           s.n[s.top]=b+c;
           break;

       case '-':
           s.n[s.top]=b-c;    
           break;

       case '*':
           s.n[s.top]=b*c;
           break;

       case '/':
           s.n[s.top]=b/c;
           break;
    }    
}

int main()
{
    s.top=-1;
    int m,i,k;

    char a[100],c[100];

    scanf("%d",&m);

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)    
    {
        int j=0;

        while(1)
        {           
            scanf("%c",a[j]);

            if(a[j]=='?')             
                break;
            else if(a[j]==' ')
            {
                push(atoi(a));
            }
            else if(a[j]=='+'||'-'||'*'||'/')
            {
                pop(a[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }

        printf("%d",s.n[s.top]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `giving runtime error` kindly explain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: Please format your code properly. You have formulated a request, but what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is *hardly* readble, still, I think, you need to change

```
scanf("%c",a[j]);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&a[j]);  //note the space before %c, and scanf() expects pointer
```

for

1. `&` because as per the `scanf()` signature, it needs the *address* to store the scanned result.
2. leading space [] to stop scanning the previously pressed ENTER [`\n`] key.

Kindly Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) of `scanf()` for more details.

Also, as mentioned in Mr. **@LPs** 's answer, usage of `push(atoi(a));` is very dangerous, in case  `a` is not null-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Chnage `scanf("%c",a[j]);` to `scanf("%c",&a[j]);`. You need to pass the address to store the value of char. Also, you would further need to discard the extra character after each input from stdin.

Comment: I have pointed out the first runtime error I saw. For further details, debug your code. Run it step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instruction `push(atoi(a));`is not safe, because of the array is not zero initialized, than atoi can fall into undefined behaviour.

Another thing is that with scanf with %c you can accept all chars (eg a, b,c) that make atoi fail.